# select box not displayed in tokenizer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use jQuery Tokenize ( http://www.jqueryrain.com/?Bxwy2bPt ). This work fine, but when I click on text field select box will not displayed. Select box will show up when I start typing first word. How can I set, that select box display already when I click on text field? My code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Tokenize-master/jquery.tokenize.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Tokenize-master/jquery.tokenize.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#tokenize').tokenize();
            });
        </script>
        <style>
            .tokenize-sample{
                width:300px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select id="tokenize" multiple="multiple" class="tokenize-sample">
            <option value="1">something1</option>
            <option value="2">something2</option>
            <option value="3">something3</option>
            <option value="4">something4</option>
            <option value="5">something5</option>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to show pulldown list when you click on text typing area, this may the one you want:

$('select#tokenize_focus').tokenize({displayDropdownOnFocus:true});

Also, please if you know, tell me how its height can be adjusted?